# Cannot fix Django NoReverseMatch error despite URL being withing urls.py

Tags: python, django

Before I go into detail, here is the line from the html document that results in the error, as well as views.py and urls.py:

`<input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia" action="{% url 'encyclopedia:findpage' %}" method="get">`

(Yes there is a space betweeen `url` and `'encyclopedia:findpage'`)

views.py findpage function:

```
def findpage(request, name):
    pages = util.list_entries()
    wanted_pages = set()
    wanted_page = None

    for page in pages:
        if not wanted_page and page == name:
            wanted_page = util.get_entry(name)
            continue

        if name in page:
            wanted_pages.add(page)

    if wanted_page:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/page.html', {
            "title": name,
            "entry": wanted_page
            })

    if wanted_pages and not wanted_page:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/index.html', {
            "entries": wanted_pages
        })

    else:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/noresults.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "encyclopedia"
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<str:name>", views.wikipage, name="wikipage"),
path("<str:name>", views.findpage, name='findpage'),
path("create", views.newpage, name="newpage")
```

]

When I run the Django project, I get a NoReverseMatch at /. The error from the webpage reads:
`In template /home/quinn/Desktop/cs50web/pset1/wiki/encyclopedia/templates/encyclopedia/layout.html, error at line 17 Reverse for 'findpage' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<name>[^/]+)$']`

Line 17 is the piece of html I left at the top of this page. I've checked numerous sources in an attempt to fix this, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: It expects a value for name, so `{% url 'encyclopedia:findpage' name='myname' %}`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I’ll be able to do `{% url ‘encyclopedia:findpage’ name={{ form.field.value|default_if_none:”” }}`

Comment: that's not pssible, since the template is rendered by the template engine *before* the result is passed to the browser.

Comment: Oh. Then I suppose I could access the form data from the views file and then pass it as context maybe?? Or would that not work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a name because your url needs it here:

```
path("<str:name>", views.findpage, name='findpage')
```

You can specify kwargs in the url tag in your template like this:

```
{% url 'reverse:lookup' kwarg='insert here the value that needs to get passed in your url' %}
```